# AlarmManager not set from Bootreceiver

Tags: android

because of the fact that the AlarmManager is being cleared when the phone is booted, I created a BootReceiver class that should reset the alarms in this case. 
But even though the other code form this class is executed somehow the AlarmManager doesn't get set, so the AlarmReceiver class is never called. Here is part of my code from the BootReceiver class:

```
    Calendar Od = Calendar.getInstance();
Od.set(yearOd, monthOd, dayOd, hourOd, minuteOd);
```

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

```
                       int id= rebootCursor.getInt(ToDoDBAdapter.ID_COLUMN);

                       Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                       i.putExtra("alarm_message", "stavi_vibracii");
                       i.putExtra("doVreme",vremeDo);
                       i.putExtra("doDatum",dateDo);
                       PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                       am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Od.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

I should note that I have registered the BootReceiver and AlarmManger in the Manifest file, and everyhting worked fine when setting the alarms within my app. If somebody had similar problems or have the answer to my question, please let me know..
Thank u

Comment: please anybody help i am also stuck in this situation.

Comment: Check out the links in the accepted answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set a wake lock to keep the phone awake long enough to complete your tasks.  See the information here:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

AND

http://www.androidguys.com/2009/04/02/wake-up-with-the-alarm/

Comment: @Sandra this solution works for you ? as per my understanding it's not what you asked, i faced the same problem alarm is not setting but other code is executing. the answer you accepted deal with alarm code or code to be executed at alarm time.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

- Your BootReceiver is implemented as a `BroadcastReceiver`
- You've added the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in your manifest

like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

- You've registered your boot receiver for the proper intent filter

like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but yes, my BootReceiver class is implemented as a BroadcastReceiver (extends BroadcastReceiver) and I have the needed permission and intent filter in my manifest. My problem is not the bootreceiver class, because this class is invoked at boot, but somehow the alarms can not be set from it. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: I also tried defining a new Service, that I start on booting on the phone, and I implemented the same (the previous code that I wrote on this thread) logic for setting the alarms but no luck :( I really don't know why it doesn't work or what am I doing so wrong...